# how to get the tree level of selected node in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

On selection of a node, I want to get its tree level and parent name also

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
        var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
        $log.log(msg+"hello"+" "+row.entity.node);
        console.log( row.entity.$$hashKey);
        selectedRow =row.entity.node;
        $scope.favName = row.entity.nodeRelPath ;
    });
```

[View this on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rV4I68QHhlh53WqZkctp?p=preview)

Comment: Okk got it ,    row.treeLevel  & row.treeNode.parentRow will give us treeLevel  & its parent object .of selected row  respectively.